# Backbone.js and node.js : how show my data in <select></select> html

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

hello i am newbie in node.js and backbone.js i need u help for my development programming..

my literature : http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/

i have code in :

node.js // mongodb database

server.js

```
app.get('/class',function(req, res) {
console.log('show all data in class');
db.collection('ak_classroom', function(err, collection) {
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.send(items);
    });
}); 
});
```

main.js

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
"class" : "show_class",
},
show_class: function(page) {
    var p = page ? parseInt(page, 10) : 1;
    var classList = new ClassCollection();
    classList.fetch({success: function(){
        $("#content").html(new classView({model: classList, page: p}).el);
    }});
    this.headerView.selectMenuItem('home-menu');
 },
});

utils.loadTemplate(['show_class_View'], function() {
app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start(); 
});
```

in models.js

//=== for get my link database mongodb get /class

```
window.class = Backbone.Model.extend({
urlRoot: "/class",

idAttribute: "_id",
//my default variable in databsae
defaults: {
    _id: null,
    sch_id : "",
cls_name: "",
    cls_description: "",
    cls_active: "",
}}); 
//get collection database 
window.classCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

model: Class,
url: "/class" });
```

in classlist.js

```
window.classView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {
    this.render();
},

render: function () {
    var class = this.model.models;
    var len = class.length;
    var startPos = (this.options.page - 1) * 100;
    var endPos = Math.min(startPos + 100, len);

    $(this.el).html('<table id="content"><thead><tr><th>ID School</th><th>Name class</th><th>Description</th></tr></thead></table>');

    for (var i = startPos; i < endPos; i++) {
        $('.content', this.el).append(new show_class_View({model: class[i]}).render().el);
    }

    return this;
}
});


window.show_class_View = Backbone.View.extend({
tagName: "tr",

initialize: function () {
    this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
},

render: function () {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
});
```

show_class_View.html

```
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= sch_id %></td>
    <td><%= cls_name %></td>
    <td><%= cls_description %></td>
    <td><%= cls_active %></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

this scema is sucess but my question how create data for

```
<select name="cls_name"  value="<%= cls_name %>">
<option><%= class[i].cls_name %></option>
</select>
```

where in select class name in array for select data ??

i am new in backbone.js so i dont know schema ?? please help i am confusion

Comment: You seem to have it right on server side, template side seems almost ok, but why don't I see a loop to create all the <option></option> ? I just see 1 line right now. If you are to iterate through class[i] you need a loop to create all options.

Comment: yeah thats true but i declare select in html my data not show error data undefined.. i am confused what to declare my model database in html..

Comment: Would you mind to setup a full example in jsfiddle or plunkr? I would look at it by then. Like this I'm not quite sure where's the problem. There are a lot of potentials.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you need to have a proper underscore templating to make your select happen. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="rate_select_template">
    <select id="rate-selector">
        <% rates.each(function(rate) { %>
            <option value="<%= rate.get('duration') %>"><%= rate.get('duration') %></option>
        <% }); %>
    </select>
</script>
```

- You can see a working example here:
  http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AEqjn/
- And the underscore template doc here: http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#template

Comment: thanks for u attention... i will try it your method is true but in backbone.js is trouble not show data...hmm..is very dificult T_T..

Comment: i try it your code but i have problem for get my database in mongodb in your code have one definition for value i need 2 definition value name and id.. this is fundamental code new in backbone.js please help me master..

Comment: You could write a JSON code within the <head> section? That would contain all of your dataset. Or you create a webservice that sends out that data and you inject this data to your template by compiling the template when you receive the JSON from your webservice?